# Open Authentication 2.0 - Inherent Security Risks

Tags: oauth, security

There are a few social networking sites which use Open Authentication 2.0. I am aware that Open Auth is vulnerable to phishing attacks, though SSL makes it unlikely. What are the security risks inherent in using Open Auth 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

This document has some good pointers on how the attack can be and what are the counter measures

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819

Hope this helped